# Is it safe to use dishes that have had turpentine on them?

Tags: safety, cleaning

A rag that had turpentine on it was rinsed off in my kitchen sink that had dishes in it. If I wash the dishes with soap and water will they be safe to use? Should I just throw out the dishes? I don’t want to be over dramatic but I also want to be safe. Thanks!

Comment: google search reveals that turpentine is toxic if you ingest several tablespoons of it, so i would not worry about it ... this is not really the place to be asking ... it is not a medical site

Comment: Tutrpentine is voltatile, if you can't smell it it has all evaporated.

Answer (score 4):

Perfectly safe. The surfactants in the soap, combined with hot water and a thorough scrubbing, would remove the turpentine effectively. Even if the dishes were of a material that was not as non-porous as, say, glazed pottery, there would still be so little residue as to make any health danger minimal (if not nil).